# Resource needed for ARM templates

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to deploy a Cosmos DB using a [CI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration)/[CD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_delivery) pipeline on [Azure DevOps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azure_DevOps_Server), using *linked templates*. I don't have much experience in linked templates. What are some resources to sample ARM templates deploying Cosmos DB on Azure using linked templates?

Answer (score 0):

The only samples created by the product team are these here which unfortunately are not linked templates. [SQL API ARM Template Samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/templates-samples-sql)

However, it's not difficult to create these. This article here shows how to compose a main template with a linked template for a storage account. And further down shows how to share parameters from the main template into the linked templates as well as output back anything back out from the linked templates through the output parameters. [Linked Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/linked-templates?tabs=azure-powershell#nested-template)